# Rescue Mode For EC2, Process Hangs On Startup

Tags: amazon-ec2, process, runlevel

I have an ec2 server that was running for several months without any problems, but I recently had to reboot due to an unknown reason.

Now, it appears that it is having trouble starting up, possible because of a script I asked it to run on startup.  Looking at the system log from the ec2 management console, I find a scary message, that I am suspicious may be the cause.

There are alternative theories, but it seems to be hanging in the middle of running my script.

Is there a way for me to boot up the server at a different run-level, or in some type of rescue mode to bypass this startup script and fix whatever is wrong?

```
[  149.318024]   

[  149.318054]   ***************************************************************

[  149.318060]   ***************************************************************

[  149.318066]   ** WARNING: Currently emulating unsupported memory accesses  **

[  149.318071]   **          in /lib/tls glibc libraries. The emulation is    **

[  149.318076]   **          slow. To ensure full performance you should      **

[  149.318081]   **          install a 'xen-friendly' (nosegneg) version of   **

[  149.318085]   **          the library, or disable tls support by executing **

[  149.318090]   **          the following as root:                           **

[  149.318095]   **          mv /lib/tls /lib/tls.disabled                    **

[  149.318100]   ** Offending process: nginx (pid=803)                        **

[  149.318105]   ***************************************************************

[  149.318109]   ***************************************************************

[  149.318117]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you can't boot an EC2 instance to rescue mode or single user mode.

If it's an [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) backed instance then you can attach the EBS root volume to another instance and access it that way.

Failing that you may have to use [AWS premium support](http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article I wrote describing how to access the root disk of an EBS boot instance that doesn't boot:

> Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance
>   http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root

You could disable the startup script and then try another boot.

The tls nosegneg warning is not likely to be causing any problems related to boot.